# user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE - in Broadleaf Commerce

Tags: java, broadleaf-commerce

I am new to the `Broadleaf Commerce` **http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started**, when I am running site on tomcat as mentioned in the steps, but I see following error coming not sure why, but I can run site : http://localhost:8080/, but when I am running Admin site https://localhost:8081/admin, I don't see anything happenings. Please guide.

The error I see

```
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_BUNDLE drop constraint FK8CC5B85F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_BUNDLE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE drop constraint FK8324FB3C15D1A13D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE drop constraint FK8324FB3C5F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE drop constraint FK8324FB3C62D84F9B
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_FEATURED drop constraint FK4C49FFE415D1A13D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_FEATURED
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_FEATURED drop constraint FK4C49FFE45F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_FEATURED
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_VALUE drop constraint FK6DEEEDBD92EA8136
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_VALUE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_XREF drop constraint FKDA42AB2F5F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_XREF drop constraint FKDA42AB2F92EA8136
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE drop constraint FKF69054F515D1A13D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE drop constraint FKF69054F55F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE drop constraint FKF69054F562D84F9B
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_OFFER_XREF drop constraint FKD592E919D5F3FAF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_OFFER_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_OFFER_XREF drop constraint FKD592E9193615A91A
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_OFFER_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_PAGE_XREF drop constraint FK874BE590883C2667
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_PAGE_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_PAGE_XREF drop constraint FK874BE590378418CD
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_PAGE_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_SC_XREF drop constraint FKC4A353AF85C77F2B
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_SC_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_SC_XREF drop constraint FKC4A353AF13D95585
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_SC_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_RATING_DETAIL drop constraint FKC9D04AD7470F437
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_RATING_DETAIL
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_RATING_DETAIL drop constraint FKC9D04ADD4E76BF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_RATING_DETAIL
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL drop constraint FK9CD7E6927470F437
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL drop constraint FK9CD7E69245DC39E0
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL drop constraint FK9CD7E692D4E76BF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_FEEDBACK drop constraint FK7CC929867470F437
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_REVIEW_FEEDBACK
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_FEEDBACK drop constraint FK7CC92986AE4769D6
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_REVIEW_FEEDBACK
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SANDBOX drop constraint FKDD37A9A174160452
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SANDBOX
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SANDBOX_MGMT drop constraint FK4845009F579FE59D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SANDBOX_MGMT
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC drop constraint FK74EEB716A1E1C128
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC drop constraint FK74EEB71671EBFA46
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_FLDGRP_XREF drop constraint FK71612AEA6A79BDB5
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC_FLDGRP_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_FLDGRP_XREF drop constraint FK71612AEAF6B0BA84
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC_FLDGRP_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_FLD_MAP drop constraint FKD948019213D95585
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC_FLD_MAP
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_FLD_MAP drop constraint FKD9480192DD6FD28A
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC_FLD_MAP
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_ITEM_CRITERIA drop constraint FK6D52BDA213D95585
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC_ITEM_CRITERIA
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_RULE_MAP drop constraint FK169F1C8256E51A06
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC_RULE_MAP
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_RULE_MAP drop constraint FK169F1C82156E72FC
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC_RULE_MAP
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_TYPE drop constraint FKE19886C3F6B0BA84
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SC_TYPE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SEARCH_FACET drop constraint FK4FFCC9863C3907C4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SEARCH_FACET
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SEARCH_FACET_RANGE drop constraint FK7EC3B124B96B1C93
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SEARCH_FACET_RANGE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SEARCH_FACET_XREF drop constraint FK35A63034DA7E1C7C
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SEARCH_FACET_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SEARCH_FACET_XREF drop constraint FK35A63034B96B1C93
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SEARCH_FACET_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_CATALOG drop constraint FK5F3F2047A350C7F1
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SITE_CATALOG
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_CATALOG drop constraint FK5F3F2047843A8B63
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SITE_CATALOG
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_MAP_CFG drop constraint FK7012930FC50D449
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SITE_MAP_CFG
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_MAP_GEN_CFG drop constraint FK1D76000A340ED71
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SITE_MAP_GEN_CFG
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_MAP_URL_ENTRY drop constraint FKE2004FED36AFE1EE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SITE_MAP_URL_ENTRY
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU drop constraint FK28E82CF73E2FC4F9
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU drop constraint FK28E82CF77E555D75
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU drop constraint FK28E82CF750D6498B
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_ATTRIBUTE drop constraint FK6C6A5934B78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_ATTRIBUTE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_BUNDLE_ITEM drop constraint FKD55968CCF29B96
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_BUNDLE_ITEM
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_BUNDLE_ITEM drop constraint FKD55968B78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_BUNDLE_ITEM
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FEE drop constraint FKEEB7181E3E2FC4F9
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_FEE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FEE_XREF drop constraint FKD88D409CB78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_FEE_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FEE_XREF drop constraint FKD88D409CCF4C9A82
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_FEE_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_EXCLUDED drop constraint FK84162D7381F34C7F
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_EXCLUDED
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_EXCLUDED drop constraint FK84162D73B78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_EXCLUDED
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_FLAT_RATES drop constraint FKC1988C9681F34C7F
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_FLAT_RATES
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_FLAT_RATES drop constraint FKC1988C96B78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_FLAT_RATES
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_MEDIA_MAP drop constraint FKEB4AECF96E4720E0
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_MEDIA_MAP
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_MEDIA_MAP drop constraint FKEB4AECF9D93D857F
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_MEDIA_MAP
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_OPTION_VALUE_XREF drop constraint FK7B61DC0BB0C16A73
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_OPTION_VALUE_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_OPTION_VALUE_XREF drop constraint FK7B61DC0BB78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_SKU_OPTION_VALUE_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_STATE drop constraint FK8F94A1EBA46E16CF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_STATE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TAR_CRIT_OFFER_XREF drop constraint FK125F5803D5F3FAF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_TAR_CRIT_OFFER_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TAR_CRIT_OFFER_XREF drop constraint FK125F58033615A91A
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_TAR_CRIT_OFFER_XREF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TAX_DETAIL drop constraint FKEABE4A4B3E2FC4F9
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_TAX_DETAIL
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TAX_DETAIL drop constraint FKEABE4A4BC50D449
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_TAX_DETAIL
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TRANS_ADDITNL_FIELDS drop constraint FK376DDE4B9E955B1D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 19:23:36 SchemaExport - user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.BLC_TRANS_ADDITNL_FIELDS
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Hibernate where this error is reporting when creating tables for the first time from an empty schema. See https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/issues/781.